# Why does ForEach behave differently than % even though they are both aliases of ForEach-Object in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

For some reason the % alias for ForEach-Object throws an exception when using the ( $Thing in $Things) syntax while the ForEach alias works fine.

Here are two examples:

**Using the % alias:**

```
$ints = @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
% ($i in $ints)
{Write-Host $i}
```

This fails with the error Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statment.

**Using the ForEach alias:**

```
$ints = @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
foreach ($i in $ints)
{Write-Host $i}
```

This succeeds without issue.

Why is there a difference if they are both aliases of ForEach-Object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are two different things:

`%` is the alias for the cmdlet `ForEach-Object` and `foreach` is *also* the alias for the cmdlet `ForEach-Object`... *and* `foreach` is a looping statement which *does not* work with pipelining.

As written, your first command expands to:

```
ForEach-Object ($i in $ints) {
  Write-Host $i 
}
```

...which isn't valid syntax for the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.

When `foreach` appears, as with your second command, it is interpreted as a `foreach` *statement*, not the cmdlet alias.  In this case the syntax *is* valid and loops as expected.

You can compare the differences with `get-help about_Foreach` and `get-help ForEach-Object`.  This blog post [Essential PowerShell: Understanding foreach](http://poshoholic.com/2007/08/21/essential-powershell-understanding-foreach/) also does a nice job explaining.

Comment: +1 Also: [PowerShell gotcha - foreach keyword vs. foreach-object cmdlet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2007/03/22/powershell-gotcha-foreach-keyword-vs-foreach-object-cmdlet.aspx)

Comment: @ChrisS that link goes to a generic archive path now